# Mixing polymorphic and 'has_many' associations

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, associations, polymorphic-associations

Two models: Review and User.

Review has three relevant fields: `user_id`, `reviewable_type`, and `reviewable_id`. So, the associations look something like this:

```
User has_many :reviews
User has_many :reviews, :as => :reviewable

Review belongs_to :user
Review belongs_to :reviewable
```

How can I find the right 'set' of reviews from the User model? `@user.reviews` vs...?

As a general case, how do we set up two models so multiple associations between them stay separate, and so the parent model can access each set of children independently?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

do you mean @user.reviews vs @user.reviewable ?

I am not that familiar with rails 3.0, but in rails 2.x you could do

```
   User has_many :review_something1, :class_name => "Review", :where => ...
   User has_many :review_something2, :class_name => "Review", :where => ...
```